# Displaying each field separated line in reverse order of fields

Tags: unix

I have the following **input**:

```
A|Bash|cat
B|bit|dog
C|Bash|apple
D|Bash|email
```

I want the following **output**:

```
cat|Bash|A
apple|Bash|C
email|Bash|D
```

The idea is to display all those lines that contain "Bash" and display their fields in reverse order.

I'm able to display these lines in the forward order using awk:

```
$ awk '/Bash/' filename.txt
```

But I can't get it to display in reverse order. Is there any way I can do this using awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F\| '/Bash/{print $3"|"$2"|"$1}' file 
cat|Bash|A
apple|Bash|C
email|Bash|D
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { 
    FS=OFS="|"                            # set the delimiters
    k="Bash"                              # set the keyword
}
$2==k {                                   # if keyword in 2nd field
    a[$1]=$3                              # hash $3 and index with 1st field
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"  # control the for traverse order
    for(i in a)                           # loop
        print a[i],k,i                    # ... and output
}' file
cat|Bash|A
apple|Bash|C
email|Bash|D
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk -F \| '/Bash/{for(i=NF;i>1;i--){printf("%s|",$i);}print $1}' filename.txt
```

where:

```
    -F \| - sets the delimiter
    /Bash/ - searching the text you want. (to be more precise you should do $2==/Bash/)
    for - loop from NF which is number of fields. here NF=3. to one above 1.
    printf = to print token i, and add the delimiter
    print - outside the loop, printing the first token. this is outside the loop to avoid having the delimiter "|" as the last character printed.
```